# error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.68

Tags: node.js, archlinux, manjaro

I got this error after installing nodejs and npm using pacman:

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.68: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/usr/local/lib/` and that hasn't worked and I also have tried looking for the file everywhere and haven't found it.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/
find / -iname libicui18n.so.68
```

Comment: Seems like a flaw in the design of NodeJS. My system uses .70 but one application requires .69 to build. If I do `ls /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.*` I only see version .70 and no previous versions. Whose fault is that? I blame NodeJS :-)

Comment: @PJBrunet - what system are you using? I started a thread on this for arch https://bugs.archlinux.org/index.php?do=details&action=details.addvote&task_id=73723

Comment: @andre Manjaro.

Comment: seems to be a regular occurrence, it happened to me once, then was fixed, now broken again....

Comment: Just for reference (I stranded here this way): [this is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55097675/4575793) for Ubuntu/Debian or other distos based on this.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue, but updating the system resolved it for me.
Use:

```
$ pacman -Syu
```

Comment: worked for me, too

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo pacman -S nodejs                                                                                                                1 ✘ 
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
:: nodejs and nodejs-lts-erbium are in conflict. Remove nodejs-lts-erbium? [y/N] y

Packages (2) nodejs-lts-erbium-12.22.11-1 [removal]  nodejs-18.7.0-1

Total Download Size:   10.22 MiB
Total Installed Size:  38.16 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      11.81 MiB
```

re-installing nodejs worked for me

Comment: Just for reference (I stranded here this way): [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155426/4575793) for Ubuntu/Debian or other distos based on this

Comment: I just got this when they retired fermium from the repos.  Same solution except I installed another LTS in its place: `pacman -S nodejs-lts-hydrogen`.  [ArchWiki: Node.js#Installation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Node.js#Installation) has the updated LTS packages.  WARNING: This solution might break some of your NodeJS apps!

Answer (score 4):

libicui18n.so.68 is provided by core/icu package and it is located in /usr/lib

```
$ pacman -F libicui18n.so
core/icu 65.1-2 [installed: 68.2-1]
usr/lib/libicui18n.so

$ pacman -Qo /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.68
/usr/lib/libicui18n.so.68 is owned by icu 68.2-1
```

Comment: changing LD_LIBRARY_PATH value not worked

Comment: Could you install or re-install the package core/icu ?
pacman -S core/icu

Comment: Check the above answer I wrote update icu package with the packages that require older version together.

Answer (score 4):

Check what version of `node-js` you are using.

Try installing `nodejs`. If you get a conflict that another `nodejs` is installed that is probably your issue.

Example:

```
nodejs and nodejs-lts-dubnium are in conflict. Remove nodejs-lts-dubnium? [y/N] y
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

Installing these libraries will solve your problem :

```
sudo pacman -Sy brltty harfbuzz-icu icu
```

**Background :**

Couldn't run samba server because of icu and when I try to update package icu it finds conflict for two dependencies. Including them solved icu installation and also solved smb service problem and cleanly restarted samba server ...
which was giving an error :

```
/usr/bin/smbd: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.71: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

icu dependency error was :

```
X@Y ~ $ sudo pacman -S icu
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: installing icu (71.1-1) breaks dependency 'libicuuc.so=70-64' required by brltty
:: installing icu (71.1-1) breaks dependency 'libicuuc.so=70-64' required by harfbuzz-icu
```

Comment: Including some libraries solved to problem brltty harfbuzz-icu and icu.  I admit the answer is not clear. However you did not concentrate on the message enough and gave a premature verdict. Thats on you. Nevertheless I fixed it for you.

Comment: I reviewed the updated answer. While it doesn't address OP head on, it gives an alternative path towards a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same approach as [the answer by MauricioOtta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73397912/4575793), if you installed node with `brew`. Then you can consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55155426/4575793), which gave me:

```
brew uninstall node
brew install node
```

It also works on Ubuntu or other distributions with home`brew` - maybe even MacOS.

*It could be possible to install `node` with `nix-env` too.*

Comment: `brew install nodejs` was enough for me to trigger the update and make this work!