# node error cannot find package Arch linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I got this error trying to run nodejs

```
node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.70: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i tried updating using

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

and i also tried removing nodejs and re-installing it with no help.

I use Arch btw.

Comment: I'm not going to vote to close this because it's kinda borderline on whether it's on-topic here, but it would be better on our [sister site unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097675/node-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libicui18n-so-62-cannot-open-shared)

Comment: @David784 arch sadly doesnt use apt. It uses pacman as its manager. so the process is kinda different.

Comment: The David784 link is about removing nodejs, and install a package that requires a "system libicu" version. ..... Alternatively you can install additional libicu : From source or with files from a package. Multiple versions are allowed, i.e. all libs have unique file names https://packages.debian.org/experimental/amd64/libicu70/filelist → Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) .... ..... ( Can be unpacked with `ar -x [package-name].deb` )

Comment: If you read the question, comments and answers, perhaps you saw @tjcrowder's comment? "A search on the error turns up several pages .... It's also important to tell us what research you've done (such as searching on the error message) and why what you found didn't help."